# Cannot add ngCookie to Angular Module with error using Bower

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, bower

After installing `Angular-Cookie` with bower and adding the js file to my HTML I cannot add ngCookies to work with it displaying the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   Dashboard due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate
>   module ngCookies due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCookies'
>   is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to
>   load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official module from **[Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies)** is called `Angular-Cookies` which can be installed using:

`bower install -s angular-cookies`

You can remove the other module by running

`bower uninstall angular-cookie`